# Why 'Fatal error: Creating User Realm Failed' error occur when I did not update any object's model?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I'm getting this fatal error when I updated to a version of my app that incorporated an additional, completely new Realm, but I did not perform any action that would have required a migration which would have resulted in this subsequent error. This error is occurring from the already existing realm `create()` method and, for context, circumstantially with the version of the app where we introduce the new Realm.

These realms I've mentioned are local realms. We are on an old version of Realm Swift - 3.19.1

Code snippet from existing realm:

```
static func create() -> Realm {
    do {
        return try Realm(configuration: config)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        fatalError("Creating User Realm Failed") // ***fails here
    }
}
    static var config: Realm.Configuration {
    let url = Realm.Configuration().fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("Users.realm")
        return Realm.Configuration(fileURL: url,
                                   schemaVersion: currentSchema, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchema in
                                    print("Old Schema version =", oldSchema)
                                    print("Current schema version =", currentSchema)
                                    print("")
                                    if oldSchema < currentSchema {
                                        if oldSchema < 108 {
                                         //old migration code 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
        }, shouldCompactOnLaunch: { (totalBytes, usedBytes) -> Bool in
            let oneHundredMB = 100 * 1024 * 1024
            return (totalBytes > oneHundredMB) && (Double(usedBytes) / Double(totalBytes)) < 0.5
        })
    }
```

Code snippet from new realm:

```
static let schemaVersion = 0

static var config: Realm.Configuration {
    return Realm.Configuration(
        fileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: RLMRealmPathForFile("Logging.realm")),
        schemaVersion: UInt64(self.schemaVersion),
        deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true,
        objectTypes: [LogSessionDBEntity.self, LogTelemetryDBEntity.self]
    )
}

static func create() -> Realm {
    do {
        return try Realm(configuration: config)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        fatalError("Creating User Realm Failed")
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing including code in the question that duplicates the issue! First, please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then include the code in your question where the error occurs, indicating which line of code failed. You need to then further clarify the question; is this local only Realm? Sync'd Realm? What OS and version of Realm are you using? How is the 'completely new realm' being instantiated? Please update the *question* with additional info and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've made edits.

Comment: Good! We need a bit more info; the error you're reporting (in the question title) is one you generated - that's not a realm error. Change your catch block to this `} catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription) }` and report back what error *Realm* is throwing. Be sure to update the code in the question so future readers will see you had good error reporting.

Comment: What error is produced with `print(error.localizedDescription)`?

Comment: I can't reliably produce it, so I will have to report back once I do